# custom text instead of path in command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

When I open CMD, I see: `C:\users\*****\>`  
how can I change this to be custom, for example: `example>`  
I'm trying to make a cmd game and want a custom start text for the command prompt,

I would prefer the answer to be able to be copy and pasted into a .bat or .cmd file, if necessary, I might be able to use a PowerShell script, but I prefer command prompt.

Comment: Open `cmd.exe` and try `PROMPT /?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I change the prompt to be custom, for example: `example>`

Use the `prompt` command:

```
prompt example$G
```

- `$G` is the `>` character.
- Make sure you have a trailing space.

Further Reading: [PROMPT - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html)